# itextsharp form name and saving pdf

Tags: pdf, itext

I am using itextsharp in ASP.NET. We populate a PDF with fields that are taken from one of our online forms. I need to change the way we handle the documents - we need to be able to use some of the fields as the name of the document(firstname-lastname.pdf), and to save that PDF into a directory. Here is the code I am using now:

```
    PdfStamper ps = null;        
        DataTable dt = BindData();
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {                
            PdfReader r = new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray("http://www.example.com/Documents/ppd-certificate.pdf"), null);
            ps = new PdfStamper(r, Response.OutputStream);

            AcroFields af = ps.AcroFields;

            af.SetField("fullName", dt.Rows[0]["fullName"].ToString());
            af.SetField("presentationTitle", dt.Rows[0]["presentationTitle"].ToString());
            af.SetField("presenterName", dt.Rows[0]["presenterFullName"].ToString());
            af.SetField("date", Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0]["date"]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));

            ps.FormFlattening = true;

            ps.Close();
        }
```

Comment: So instead of sending the PDF to the `Response.OutputStream` you want to write to disk? Is that your question?

Comment: Currently the above code prints the PDF to the browser. But I would like to send the PDF to a directory on a network drive instead.

Answer (score 1):

`PdfStamper` and `PdfWriter` both use the generic `Stream` class so instead of `Response.OutputStream` you can use a [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx) or a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream(v=vs.110).aspx)

This example writes directly to disk. Set `testFile` to whatever you want, I'm using the desktop here

```
//Your file path here:
var testFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "test.pdf");
using (var fs = new FileStream(testFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
    PdfReader r = new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray("http://www.example.com/Documents/ppd-certificate.pdf"), null);
    var ps = new PdfStamper(r, fs);
    //..code
}
```

This next example is my preferred method. It creates a `MemoryStream`, then creates a PDF inside of it and finally grabs the raw bytes. Once you've got raw bytes you can both write them to disk AND `Response.BinaryWrite()` then.

```
byte[] bytes;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    PdfReader r = new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray("http://www.example.com/Documents/ppd-certificate.pdf"), null);
    var ps = new PdfStamper(r, ms);
    //..code

    bytes = ms.ToArray();
}

//Your file path here:
var testFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "test.pdf");

//Write to disk
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(testFile, bytes);

//Send to HTTP client
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. Is it possible to save the file using fields from the form i.e. firstname-lastname.pdf?

Comment: Yep, in either sample above just replace the `test` file with your appropriate path and use whatever logic you want for naming the file.